# Estimate the error due to replacing the sum of the series with its first n terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Estimate the error due to replacing the sum of the series with
the sum of the first $n$ terms.

$1+ \frac{1}{2!} - \frac{1}{3!} + \frac{1}{4!}-...+\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}+...$

The hint in the textbook says $R_n = a_n(\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{2^2} \cdot \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}+ \ ...)$.

I've tried proving\checking it, but I still don't know where it comes from.

I know that in this case $R_n=a_n(\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} + \ ...)$. Could you tell me how to rewrite it using $\frac{1}{2}$ ?

Comment: If the series (apart from first term) is as you write, and $|a_n|=\frac{1}{n!}$ (it has not been defined) then $R_n$ as hinted at in the textbook is wrong. Such a mistake is implausible.

Comment: Well, that's what the hint says and $a_n$ isn't specified there either. I also assumed that $a_n = (-1)^{n} \frac{1}{n!}$. Could you tell me how to estimate the remainder?

Comment: This is an **alternating series**. The absolute value of the error in such cases is less than the first "neglected" term. Important, easy! If we did not have the minus signs, as in the series for $e^x$, we would say the error is less than $\frac{1}{n!}\left (\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\cdots \right)$, an easily summed geometric series. By the way, your series is a little weird, the first term doesn't "fit." Yours is the series for $1+e^{-1}$.

Comment: Please summarize the above comments into an answer and accept it to close the matter. Also check the textbook, and report the problem if you didn't misread.

Comment: All right, I will, thank you.